# Can't generate ons-list using javascript [OnsenUI]

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I am trying to fetch data from a remote server and display it on the `<ons-list>`. The `append` javascript function can't be used for the `<ons-list>`. It displays nothing on the screen.

Here's my javascript:

```
function loadCourses() 
    {
        var bugs = $('#courses');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '#myserverurlgoeshere',
            dataType: 'JSONp',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                bugs.append('<ons-list>');
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    bugs.append('<ons-list-item class="assgn-list"><h3>'+item.courseName+'</h3><h5>'+item.courseID+'</h5></ons-list-item>');
                });
                bugs.append('</ons-list>');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                bugs.append('<li>There was an error loading the bugs');
            }
        });
    }
```

Heres my html file:

```
<div id="courses">
    <script>loadCourses();</script>
</div>
```

And I want it to display like this:
[image]

**UPDATES**
Here's my `index.html` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/plugin-loader.css">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/plugin-loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fetchData.js"></script>


  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);   

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {        
           yepnope({
              test : window.device.platform === 'iOS' && parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0,
              yep  : 'css/ios7.css',
            });
    }

    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
  </script>
</head>

<body>    
  <ons-screen page="tabbar.html"></ons-screen>
</body>
</html>
```

My `tabbar.html`

```
<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tabbar-item active="true" page="page1.html">
        <img class="tabbar-icon" src="images/icons/paperclip.png"/>
        <h5 class="tabbar-text">Assignments</h5>
    </ons-tabbar-item> 

    <ons-tabbar-item page="page2.html">
        <img class="tabbar-icon" src="images/icons/alarm.png"/>
        <h5 class="tabbar-text">Reminders</h5>
    </ons-tabbar-item>

    <ons-tabbar-item page="page3.html">
        <img class="tabbar-icon" src="images/icons/Calendar_icon.png"/>
        <h5 class="tabbar-text">Timetable</h5>
    </ons-tabbar-item> 

    <ons-tabbar-item page="page4.html">
        <img class="tabbar-icon" src="images/icons/Contact_book_icon.png"/>
        <h5 class="tabbar-text">Courses</h5>
    </ons-tabbar-item> 
</ons-tabbar>
```

My `page4.html`

```
<ons-page class="page center">
    <ons-navigator page="courses.html" title="COURSES"></ons-navigator>
</ons-page>
```

My `courses.html`

```
<div ng-controller="CoursesPageController">
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item ng-show="error">
            There was an error loading the courses
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="assgn-list" ng-repeat="course in courses">
            <h3>{{course.courseName}}</h3>
            <h5>{{course.courseID}}</h5>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</div>
```

My `fetchData.js`

```
function CoursesPageController($scope){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '#myserverurl',
        dataType: 'JSONp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
                $scope.courses = data;
                $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(data) {
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**page1.js**

```
function Page1Controller($scope){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '#myserverurlgoeshere',
        dataType: 'JSONp',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
                $scope.courses = data;
                $scope.$apply();
        },
        error: function(data) {
                $scope.error = true;
             $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

}
```

**page1.html**

```
<ons-page class="center">
    <div ng-controller="Page1Controller">
        <ons-list>
            <ons-list-item ng-show="error">
                There was an error loading the bugs
            </ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item class="assgn-list" ng-repeat="course in courses">
                <h3>{{course.courseName}}</h3>
                <h5>{{course.courseID}}</h5>
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

You can see the demo here http://kruyvanna.github.io/Blog_Demos/onsen_ui/list/app/

and the complete source code here http://kruyvanna.github.io/Blog_Demos/onsen_ui/list/list_demo.zip .

Comment: Thanks a lot @vanna . Im a noob in AngularJS. BTW, why does the list only appears when I touch the screen?

Comment: I am not so sure, but it's the css and the browser on some devices. Can you tell your device info like: maker, os version ...

Also always remember $scope.$apply(); after you do ajax or other async stuff outside of anguarljs like $.ajax()

Comment: I am runnung the Monaca Debugger on iPhone 4S running iOS7.1.4. I am not using any other ajax. Or is it because i'm running OnsenUI 0.6.0?

Comment: ...tried updating to OnsenUI 1.0 but its the same. Only appears when I touch the screen.

Comment: is this happening to Onsen UI only? Could you try other project? like Minimum Project. I want to confirm if it's Onsen UI or the Debugger.

Comment: Found out the problem: The problem is when displaying the list using a Tabbar. I have 4 tabs and the screen is empty when a tab is selected. Touching the screen then displays the list. (p.s It works fine in Minimum Project. Tabbar is the problem.)

Comment: So,how do I solve this problem? Is the problem with OnsenUI Tabbar?

Comment: I have added the codes for `index.html`, `tabbar.html`, `page4.html`, `courses.html` and `fetchData.js` above in the question section

Comment: I see you have tab1 active. 
    
    <ons-tabbar-item active="true" page="page1.html">
        <img class="tabbar-icon" src="images/icons/paperclip.png"/>
        <h5 class="tabbar-text">Assignments</h5>
    </ons-tabbar-item>

Is it safe to say that page1.html is not displayed until the screen is touched?

In that case, can you post page1.html and its related pages?

Comment: actually the tab4 should be active. I am only working with the page4. The other pages are kinda empty(with some dummy text) for now. When I tap Tab4 it appears empty and when I touch the screen, then the list appears.

Comment: or is there something wrong with ng-translude and ng-controller? Read somewhere that it conflicts.

Comment: Tried the same ng-controller using the Onsen-UI Sliding Menu + Navigator template and got this error `ERROR: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/ng/areq?p0=CoursesPageController&p1=not<div class="center page" ng-transclude="">0a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: This is because angularjs cannot find your controller (CoursesPageController). make sure your path to fetchData.js is correct.

Comment: Ops..yeah my mistake. And for the tabbar issue, it works properly when I built the app and run on Andorid 4.4.2. I think the problem is with the ios debugger. Might wanna look into it some time. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: For the issue of list has to be touched. I am able to reproduce it now. After I upgrade to Onsen UI 1.0, it's working fine. But you need to change <tab-bar-item label="..." icon="your-css-class">